# Object comprehension with iterator

Tags: jsonnet

I have a given object `renameByName` like that:

```
{
  fieldA: 'foo',
  fieldB: 'bar'
}
```

and I want to convert that into an object that is supposed to order the fields by an index:

```
{
  fieldA: 0,
  fieldB: 1,
}
```

**My idea:**

```
      {
        [key]: 0,
        for key in std.objectFields(renameByName)
      }
```

That would yield:

```
{
  fieldA: 0,
  fieldB: 0,
}
```

**Full reference code:**

```
  organizeTransformation(renameByName):: {
    id: "organize",
    options: {
      excludeByName: {},
      indexByName: {
        [key]: 0,
        for key in std.objectFields(renameByName)
      },
      renameByName: renameByName,
    },
  },
```

**My question:**

Because Jsonnet doesn't have iterators for loops I'm unsure how I could use a counter here?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
  organizeTransformation(renameByName):: {
    local keys = std.objectFields(renameByName),
    id: "organize",
    options: {
      excludeByName: {},
      indexByName: {
        [keys[i]]: i,
        for i in std.range(0, std.length(keys) - 1)
      },
      renameByName: renameByName,
    },
  },
```